# How can I set tick marks on the x axis in RectangleChart?

Tags: plotting

How it is possible to put ticks on the x-axis in `RectangleChart`?

The proposed solution, `BarSpacing -> None`, doesn't work with Mathematica 10.

Comment: Where did see `BarSpacing -> None`  proposed as a solution to your problem?

Comment: I found this answer proposed by "Brett Champion" on mathematica.stachexchange "answered Sep 18 '12 at 18:52" to the question "How can I set the tick marks of the x axis in RectangleChart?"

Comment: `RectangleChart[{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {3, 4}}, BarSpacing -> None]` works fine in V11.1. If this was a buggy in V10, it has been fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like using [`Ticks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks.html) doesn't work. A workaround is to use a [`Frame`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Frame.html) and then you can use [`FrameTicks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameTicks.html) instead. If you want to keep only the left and bottom parts of the `Frame`, to resemble the usual axes, you can use `Frame->{{True, False}, {True, False}}` like this:

```
RectangleChart[{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}}, 
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {{0.3, 1, Pi}, Automatic}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {{38, 13}, {24, 23}, {20, 7}, {18, 11}};
```

Simply use `Frame -> True` and put the category names (if needed) inside the bars

```
RectangleChart[data,
 ChartLabels -> Placed[{"Tony", "Fred", "Anna", "Snoopy"}, Center, Rotate[#, Pi/2] &],
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that I need also to add something like "FrameTicks -> True"